# Find nth file in directory alphabetically in linux

Tags: terminal

Anyone know a bash command that I could use to find the nth file in a directory?
E.g. I have the 4 files in my directory

aaa, aab, aac, aad.

(My actual directory has a lot more than 4 files)

What command could I write to get the 3rd file(aac)?

Another question would be how to find the index position of aac(via terminal command) (i.e. it's 3)

Comment: If you want the 3rd file I assume you *have* the index. If you know the name and want the number, that's a little more complex. When you say "file", do you mean *plain* file? Is it enough to include "entries" in the directory? What about hidden files? Subdirectories? Please elaborate your specifications, and show what you have tried (c.f. [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for guidance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplistically,

```
lst=(*)
echo "${lst[2]}" # shows the 3rd file.
```

If what you want is to know where in the list `aac` occurs,

```
for((i=0;i<${#lst[@]};i++)); do 
  if [[ aac == "${lst[i]}" ]]; then echo "$i"; break; fi
done
2
```

If you want non-zero ordinals, `echo "$((i+1))"`.

This becomes more complicated if you want to include "hidden" files, and/or exclude directories, etc... It's just a matter of adding a few lines of code to mitigate details.

## late addendum

```
$: i=0; declare -A plain=(); # initialize a counter and a lookup table
$: for f in * .*; do [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue; plain[$f]=$((i++)); done
$: echo ${plain[aac]}
2
$: declare -p plain
declare -A plain=([aad]="3" [aab]="1" [aac]="2" [aaa]="0" )

$: ls -lF
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 17 08:45 aaa
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 17 08:45 aab
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 17 08:45 aac
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 17 08:45 aad
drwxr-xr-x 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 17 08:46 bar/
```

`*` grabs all visible; `.*` picks up "hidden" files if you want them.
The `-f` is an example of checking for "plain" files only, not directories or FIFOs, etc.
The assignment of the self-incrementing counter in an Associative array - a lookup table - with filename as the key lets you ask quickly "which index is file so-and-so?"

Answer (score 1):

you can use head and tail

example: to find the 100th File in /etc

ls /etc | head -n 100 | tail -n 1